# about KNN parameter K value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

[This is the first method to know which one is best K value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Ac6.jpg)

[This is the second method to know which one is best K value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAzkn.jpg)

[vivualzation for pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKD3L.jpg)

Just wonder which method is better and why ?

Thank you

Comment: Why not use both data? Normally you would want to have a high accuracy and low error rate. The error rate is to ensure you are not over fitting your data.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first is preferred, Because it uses Cross-Validation to test accuracy(generally performance) of k-value, thus best accuracy of K is more authentic in first method. KNN is very vulnerable to local minimum, so you definitely need Cross-validation technique more than always.
2. You should compare two method with same metrics, so plot accuracy for both of them.
3. Apparently best value of K occurs somewhere about 15-20 because in both plot has best performance. I recommend you to try Cross-validation for k in range(15-20) with higher fold value(in first method cv>>10)
4. Consider [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384542/how-to-prevent-overfitting-with-knn) about over fitting and value of k.